# Celery tasks from different applications in different log files

Tags: redis, celery, freebsd, celery-task, celery-log

I'm looking for configure `Celery` on my `FreeBSD` server and I get some issues according to log files.

**My configuration:**

- FreeBSD server
- 2 Django applications : app1 and app2
- Celery is daemonized and Redis
- Each application has his own Celery task

**My Celery config file:**

I have in **/etc/default/celeryd_app1** :

```
# Names of nodes to start
CELERYD_NODES="worker"

# Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
CELERY_BIN="/usr/local/www/app1/venv/bin/celery"

# App instance to use
CELERY_APP="main"

# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYD_CHDIR="/usr/local/www/app1/src/"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"

# Set logging level to DEBUG
#CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="DEBUG"

# %n will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/app1/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/app1/%n.pid"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"

# If enabled pid and log directories will be created if missing,
# and owned by the userid/group configured.
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
```

I have exactly the same file for **celeryd_app2**

**Django settings file with Celery settings:**

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = False
CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
# Add a one-minute timeout to all Celery tasks.
CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT = 60
```

Both settings have the same redis' port.

**My issue:**

When I execute a celery task for app1, I find logs from this task in app2 log file with an issue like this :

```
Received unregistered task of type 'app1.task.my_task_for_app1'
...
KeyError: 'app1.task.my_task_for_app1'
```

There is an issue in my Celery config file ? I have to set different redis port ? If yes, How I can do that ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem lies in the fact that you are using the same Redis database for both applications:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
```

Take a look into [the guide](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html) for using Redis as a broker. Just change the database for each application, e.g.

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
```

and

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/1'
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it didn't work. But the issue comes from my mistake. I restarted both celeryd tasks but I didn't make a `touch` to reload django settings. I need some tries, but it seems to work !